# How to count occurrences in jsonb array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How to count the occurrences in a jsonb array with Postgres?

Let's say we want to count how many times "a" is in the following jsonb array:

```
["a", "b", "a"]
```

The the result should be:  2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unnest and then count:

```
select count(*)
from jsonb_array_elements_text('["a", "b", "a"]'::jsonb) as x(e)
where x.e = 'a';
```